# How to change user home folder in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: windows-10, azure-activedirectory, intune

Is there a way to change default user home folder naming in Azure Active Directory? I am thinking about switching to Microsoft 365 E3 or E5 and join my computers into domain but when I did trial, after joining domain Windows created home folder with NameSurname format.

For example, I created a new user in AAD, like John Doe, and when I join Windows 10 computer to domain, or even install it via Auto Pilot, it creates a folder named C:\Users\JohnDoe

I need to customize it, like JDoe or John.Doe or even number like U-0001

It is a big problem because names include non Latin characters, like ü ö ä ß, etc and this causes lots of issues with applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual solution but workaround.

Change 'Display Name' in AAD for user to whatever format you want. Install Windows 10. Login with that user. Then change 'Display Name' in AAD to original value. Sync with AAD. Restart computer.